# How to disable Intellij wrapping on @ in match statements in Scala?

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij formats the following match statement

```
case product @ Product(id, name) =>
   ....
```

to

```
 case product@Product(id, name) =>
    ....
```

How do I disable the wrapping ? The wrapping makes it harder to read the code where are too many cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming, you are using IDEA 15.

1. Go to Preferences
2. In the left panel, select Editor > Code Style > Scala
3. Select the 'Spaces' tab
4. Scroll down in the checkbox list
5. Check Spaces around '@' in pattern bindings

[image]